# Testing a implemented algorithm in cryptography

Tags: testing, cryptography

I have implemented a cryptography algorithm using my own code using `C#.net`,

i need to test this **implemented algorithm** for its accuracy and execution time ..

is there a standard way which i can test these algorithm for its accuracy and execution time?

this algo is implemented as class in `C#.net`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two obvious ways, and you should do both. Test it against a respected existing implementation, and test it using known good test vectors such as the known answer tests (KAT) supplied by the U.S. NIST for algorithms in their standards. Most algorithms in the IETF RFCs also have test values.

Comment: thanks do u have any idea how to test stenography algo too ? [which is working but test for various accuracy and execution time and i tested in several machines with different specs can it be a standard test ? ]

Comment: [Steganography](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Steganography) is the word I think you are looking for. That is much harder to test. You can certainly test the underlying cryptography using the approach I outlined, but you probably need to get an expert to evaluate the quality of the hiding technique.